# Javascript - Replace substring if the substring is not prepended with a character Regex or other

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substr

I need to replace all instances of a string(needle) within another string(haystack), but only where the needle is not preceeded by a specific character, in this case '-'

```js
var needle = 'secret';
var haystack = 'secret title date user -secret secret something.secret';

//Regex that needs to be adjusted
var result = haystack.replace(/secret/g, '');

//Desired result is
var desiredResult = ' title date user -secret  something.';
```

Comment: Must the answer be a regex solution or you just want it to work?

Comment: Just need it to work. But i think i've got a regex working now